# Drop down category main menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm newbie on Wordpress. Currently I'm developing a blog using Wordpress 3.3. For now I have 4 main article categories Javascript, Gammu, PHP and Oracle. I have put all of these categorie in the main menu. You can check it on [Programming Tutorial](http://www.semurjengkol.com)

My question is: can I have a single dropdown menu called category and if the user move the cursor over it, all categories would be listed?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by Just making some CSS tricks :)

This will help you! Add this to your `style.css`

```
  li ul {display: none;} 
  li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: Can you detail your answer. where is the style.css location. and how to add category into main menu? thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an older example that I used: http://jsfiddle.net/99Rz9/1/

What's good about this, is that the menu is toggled so the user can move his mouse freely and the menu won't hide. Another thing is that when Javascript is disabled, the menu will be shown anyway (So also a good alternative for mobile phones!)